# While saving image in databse using struts2 it show error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, struts2

1. While saving image in databse using Struts2 it show

   error:`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Are you using eclipse or any other IDE.

Comment: The first action, on receiving some exception that you don't understand, should be using search, not posting it as a question.

Comment: Please provide some more details. I am not sure I guess in place of saving images, you should save image path in database.

Comment: How big is the image; does it work with smaller images; have you tried running the JVM with more heap size, etc. There many many questions you could **easily** ask & answer yourself before coming up with such a low quality question on stack overflow.

Comment: How big is the image and how much memory is available to Java?

Comment: @RomanC  60 mb image file size

Comment: It's not so big, my java is using 1GB, can you post a stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase the VM heap space, to do that use the following in the VM arguments :

`-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` (or any base2 number you need based on your memory).

If this doesn't fix it, you can use a profiler to watch your memory and trace objects usage and method timings. You can use [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) for example.